# ChartJS update data with a colour

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Evening all, I have a function to update the data in my ChartJS chart, however it will always update with a solid blue colour, I also have a function to get a random rgba colour however I am having trouble mating the two, code below and any help would be appreciated!

```
function updateData() {
    removeData(bubbleChart);
    bubbleChart.data.labels.push("Test","test 2",);
    bubbleChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push([45111.00,61.97,10],[1421413.00,236.55,10],);
    });
    bubbleChart.data.backgroundColor.push(randomColor())
    bubbleChart.update();
}
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'bubbleChart.backgroundColor.push')

Comment: Have you checked that your `randomColor` function is workin as expected? You could do that by adding a simple `console.log(randomColor())` before you try to set the chart color.

Comment: @norie yeah it works to initially render the chart and does designate random colours so I assume it would work the same when updating ?

Answer (score 0):

The data does not have a backgroundColor. The backgroundColor is specified in the datasets itself. So you will need to target the specific dataset first you want to push the background color too. Or since you make it a random color you can just put it in your loop where you push the data.

```js
function updateData() {
    removeData(bubbleChart);
    bubbleChart.data.labels.push("Test","test 2",);
    bubbleChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push([45111.00,61.97,10],[1421413.00,236.55,10],);
        dataset.backgroundColor.push(randomColor())
    });
    bubbleChart.update();
}
```